# is there a way to replace old values of 1 column of table based on a new value of similar table in pandas

Tags: pandas, updates

I have 1 table that contain 15k rows and it show an overdue account of who 
    paid and who hasn't paid. the 2nd table show the id and account of people 
    who have paid. I'm trying to figure the best way to update the first table 
from overdue to paid. 
this is the first table called "overdue"

```
Id         Name      Account
300         Sandy      paid
301        Stack       paid
302        Que         overdue
303         Liz        overdue
304        Grace       overdue
305          DP        overdue
306        Batty       overdue
307         tako       overdue
```

this is the 2nd updated table based on the end of the month closure "paid 
     table"

```
 Id         Name      Account
 300         Sandy      paid
 301        Stack       paid
 302        Que         paid
 303         Liz        overdue
 304        Grace       paid
 305          DP        paid
 306        Batty       paid
 307         tako       paid
```

I'm trying to have the table look like this.

```
 Id         Name      Account
 300         Sandy      paid
 301        Stack       paid
 302        Que         paid
 303         Liz       overdue
 304        Grace       paid
 305          DP        paid
 306        Batty       paid
 307         tako       paid
```

I tried this code and not sure the best way to do it for 15k id that has 
   updated account

```
df1.loc[df1['ID'] == 300, ['Name']] = 'Paid'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `update`

```
df1.set_index('Id',inplace=True)
df1.update(df2.set_index('Id')[['Account']])
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df1
Out[289]: 
    Id   Name  Account
0  300  Sandy     paid
1  301  Stack     paid
2  302    Que     paid
3  303    Liz  overdue
4  304  Grace     paid
5  305     DP     paid
6  306  Batty     paid
7  307   tako     paid
```

Comment: i tried using the syntax mentioned above but for some reason it giving me this error:  cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. any idea on how i can overcome that

Answer (score 1):

You can also select the column using a merge:

```
In [11]: df2.merge(df1[["Id"]], how="right")["Account"]
Out[11]:
0       paid
1       paid
2       paid
3    overdue
4       paid
5       paid
6       paid
7       paid
Name: Account, dtype: object
```

Slightly more efficiently (by only selecting the columns you need):

```
In [12]: df2[["Id", "Account"]].merge(df1[["Id"]], how="right")["Account"]
Out[12]:
0       paid
1       paid
2       paid
3    overdue
4       paid
5       paid
6       paid
7       paid
Name: Account, dtype: object
```

Now you can update:

```
In [13]: df1.update(df2[["Id", "Account"]].merge(df1[["Id"]], how="right")["Account"])

In [14]: df1
Out[14]:
    Id   Name  Account
0  300  Sandy     paid
1  301  Stack     paid
2  302    Que     paid
3  303    Liz  overdue
4  304  Grace     paid
5  305     DP     paid
6  306  Batty     paid
7  307   tako     paid
```

*Note: Both these assume that every id in df2 exists in df1. if this is not the case you should create a new DataFrame, with an outer join, rather than update df1.*

Comment: everything that is in df2 is also in df1. when using the query that you provided I only get the same row that is in df2 but no id that was df1 comes back

Comment: @cesco I don't understand your issue, could you try explaining with an example? Or point to the index in the df1 which is incorrect/missing

Comment: df1 has 20k rows and df2 has 3k rows. all the id that are in df2 are also found in df1. the goal is to change the info found in the account of df1 based on the updated version of df2. when i follow your query only the the rows in df2 and column of df1 was return. I hope I'm explain well this time. Thanks for your help

Comment: @cesco that's strange, I would think this should work. I'll give a try later, perhaps I'm missing something